# 2 Different Taxonomy with Hierarchical Term Relationship

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I'm searching a way to combine two different taxonomy by it's term. Here is a picture of what I'm trying to achieve

[image: screenshot]

[image: relation]

I will used this later in a drop down select box with Ajax, if it choose Make Audi, then model will be generating model for Audi. Is it possible to linking the term like I described?

Comment: Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve, what you've tried yourself so far and what's not working properly with your solution.

Comment: @engelen I've added a new screenshot for more specific what I'm trying to achieve, my solution is working but confusing for user.